# Use other project/solution in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Hey everyone I have two projects created with Visual Studio and I want to use project A in project B. Therefore I right clicked in Visual Studio on project B and added project A as an additional include directory under "C/C++" in the properties of my project.

Everything works fine, the "#include" finds my files but when I want to build project B I get an unresolved external link error.

However if I move the files of the other project into the second project and change the "#include " to "#include "myfile.h" " everything works fine.

Why does it through the error if I do not copy the files of project A into project B even though I added the folder of project A to the additional include directories?

Comment: So A and B are both executable projects (producing a .exe) in different solutions and you want to share some source files between the two?

Comment: Not quite. In A I created a c++ class which I also want to use in project B. Project A has a Test.cpp in it which uses this class and builds into an exe and project B wants to use the same class of A but turns into a dll

Comment: Then probably you forgot to "add file to project" for your related .cpp file. The include path only relates to header files and maybe your class implementation in a .cpp file also is important.

Comment: Aaah okey, I though adding it to includes is enough. Thanks